# Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pygobject

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
```

I'm getting this error while importing the `pygobject` module. I don't know how to solve the problem.
Any one has any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

I tried pip install PyGObject
pip install -m PyGObject
still getting the error in downloading the file

Comment: might be worth showing the relevant `toml` file.

Comment: The correct way is `py -m pip install PyGObject` Released: about 5 hours ago

Comment: What OS are you using and what's your python version?